# Qtiles on QGIS + QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-server

I have just created some tiles on my project on QGIS with the plugin Qtiles; now I get several tiles in .png!
My question is, how could put these tiles .png on QGIS Server? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried to publish your QGIS project on QGIS server as explain [here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial)?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to install qgis server on windows 7 but i have some error! But even if i do, i don't know how to load my .png on server!
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Do you really need to use Qtiles or your first goal is to create a WMTS layer with QGIS Server?

Comment: This is my aim: experimenting if it is possible publish tiles (image in png) created with Qtiles and AGBO (Arcmap) on Opens Source Server, so i trying to understand if i can load the images, and after that the service WTMS!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of QTiles, it seems you have to create your own server to serve those tiles or put them in a WMTS server.

QGIS Server is not a WMTS Server. One workaround might be to use Lizmap plugin and its [cached and tiled option](http://docs.3liz.com/en/lizmap-plugin/interface/layers-tab.html). Lizmap will come on top of QGIS Server to publish layers as tiled cached WMS layers. Most parts of the documentation are in french though.

If you're free to use another GIS Server, you should look at WMTS Servers like [Mapserver/Mapcache](http://mapserver.org/mapcache/services.html), [GeoServer/GeoWebCache](http://geoserver.org/), [ROK4](http://www.rok4.org/) or others...

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, but then what sense does make it in .png if I can not publish them? P.S. I am sorry for "answer"